# React Native: Way to restart apps in users devices remotely without injecting code

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

I have a React Native app.

I realized I didn't inject any code to restart app in certain condition
(e.g. when update detected, force restart, reload)

Is there anyway to apply updates to apps in users devices?
Like by command line specifying device id or something?

Thank you.

Comment: No I don't think so. At least that i know off

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So I will think of a way before it's too late.